# Deleting and re-uploading products after Shopify theme redevelopment

Tags: database, shopify, product

I am looking for advice on the best practice for removing a Shopify store's current database of products and re-uploading a new product list to the database. I'm hoping this will calm my nerves and ensure I am following the best way to achieve my desired result.

So I have 50,000+ products that I uploaded to my development site. I have then gone on to build the website including the product pages, collections and all the bells and whistles.

Now all the features are added, I have been given a new product database to upload, where some products have been dropped, a lot have been updated and a lot have been given new tags or product types.

As it is such a large change to the product list I would ideally be able to delete the existing database, then upload the new product database (as they are so different). I have also made changes myself to a lot of the products to test discounts and other general testing purposes, so these changes would be rectified without my involvement and will match the new product export I have been given.

So all this in mind, **am I able to delete the whole range of products loaded in, re-upload the new list, while maintaining the existing collections and tag filters?**

I appreciate this is not a question I can provide code examples of, more a resource for best steps to completely refresh a product database while maintaining existing collection and tagging.

Answer (score 0):

Your requirement is quite possible, but, it may take you a lot of time to fix the issue. Below is my suggestion:

1. Export all your current products from Shopify admin console
2. Compare with the new file you have
3. If you notice a change then update the same in Shopify using the product id(if you have it) or you can use the product-handle
4. Finally, remove the products that are not present in the new file

Comment: Thanks for commenting, I am going to try the other answer and see how that goes. I appreciate this is most likely the safest way to achieve the desired results.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, delete all products in your shop. That cleans up everything. Import the new product CSV. Done...

A script to delete all products is pretty simple code. Using the Shopify command line tools, you can quickly validate your shop is ready for new products.

Comment: Thanks for chipping in, I have began this process and will feedback upon completion.